# 400 error on Vercel app with Auth0 after login

Tags: next.js, auth0, vercel

I’ve set the auth0 athentication up in my Next.js app and deployed to vercel. It works on localhost as expected. However, on the live Vercel app, after selecting login from my webpage, it takes me to the auth0 login page, but after I login it gives me a blank page with a 400 GET error. The GET URL is https://{my app}.vercel.app/api/auth/callback? followed by code & state values.

I've added the right Env variables in the Vercel project and linked to them using a .env.production which I got from documentation i read online.

This is the .env.production file which has the same values as the .env.local but on the Vercel dashboard:

```
    AUTH0_SECRET=${AUTH0_SECRET}
    AUTH0_BASE_URL=${AUTH0_BASE_URL}
    AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL={AUTH0_ISSUER_BASE_URL}
    AUTH0_CLIENT_ID=${AUTH0_CLIENT_ID}
    AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET=${AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by creating a brand new app in Auth0 and hooked it up.